# Examples of interesting / non-trivial manifolds that are direct products

Tags: geometry, manifolds, examples-counterexamples, direct-product

What are interesting / non-trivial examples of smooth connected closed manifolds that are direct products or involve direct products? I am especially interested in orientable manifolds.

Say, an $n$-torus $T^n$ is a direct product of $n$ copies of a circumference $S^1$. One can build a 3-manifold from a surface of genus $g$ as $M=M^2_g\times S^1$, and use somehow the connected sums of such manifolds.

Typically an "important" manifold would have a name or standard notation. For example, the Kodaira-Thurston manifold (important if it has a proper name!) decomposes into a product of the Heisenberg nil manifold and $S^1$.

I am looking for other important / interesting / non-trivial manifolds that happen to be direct products, preferably having important / interesting applications.

Comment: $\mathbb R^n{}$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Thank you! Unfortunately, $\mathbb R^n$ is not closed.

Comment: Ah. I missed the closed part. *Why* are you interested in such a list, by the way? It seems quite random really...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez We are working on a paper where the main result is a theorem about direct product of closed manifolds, and I need to explain why this is important and where the theorem can be applied.

Comment: Can you find a product of closed manifolds that's not interesting?

Comment: @MikeMiller (Joke: all natural numbers are interesting. Proof by induction: consider the smallest non-interesting number.) Yes, when we proved the theorem, this was our logic. But I think $M^2_7\times M^2_{12}\times S^1$ would not be a convincing example for the reviewers. In the question I added a "definition": an important manifold has a proper name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Lie groups $U(n)$ are diffeomorphic to products $SU(n)\times S^1$ (but are *not* Lie isomorphic, unless $n=1$).

The Lie group SO(8) is diffeomorphic (but not Lie isomorphic) to $SO(7)\times S^7$.  (In fact, $S^7$ doesn't have a Lie group structure at all.)

The Lie group $SO(4)$ is diffeomorphic (but not Lie isomorphic) to $S^3\times \mathbb{R}P^3\cong S^3\times SO(3)$.

(To my knowledge, Lie groups with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(8)$ are the only simple Lie group which are diffeomorphic to nontrivial products).

Relatedly, the unit tangent bundles to $S^1$, $S^3$, and $S^7$ are diffeomorphic to products $S^{k-1}\times S^k$, and no other unit tangent bundles of spheres are.

Comment: Thanks to all, all answers are excellent and useful (I upvoted all of them), but the system requires me to choose only one, so I had to choose one. This answer contains three slightly different examples.

Answer (score 8):

A non degenerate  (=rank $4$) complex quadratic form $q(x,y,z,t)$ defines a smooth   quadric $Q=V(q)=\{q=0\}\subset \mathbb P^3(\mathbb C)$.
This quadric is  a complex manifold of dimension $2$ and thus a compact differential manifold of real dimension $4$.
An elementary but extremely beautiful theorem in algebraic geometry states that every such quadric $Q$ is algebraically isomorphic to $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)\times \mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)$ and so *a fortiori* diffeomorphic to the product $S^2\times S^2$ of two spheres.

A completely explicit example is given by the quadratic form $q(x,y,z,t)=xt-yz$.
An isomorphism of algebraic varieties between $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)\times \mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)$ and the  quadric $Q$ given by the equation  $xt-yz=0$ is supplied by the so-called Segre map:

$$ \mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)\times \mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)\stackrel {\cong}{\to} Q:([t:u],[v:w]) \mapsto  [x:y:z:t]=[tv:tw:uv:uw]                                $$

Answer (score 4):

Let $M$ and $N$ be homeomorphic, simply connected, smooth 4-manifolds. (They need not be diffeomorphic - that's why this is interesting.) Then there is some $k$ such that $M \; \sharp \; k(S^2 \times S^2) \cong N \; \sharp \; k(S^2 \times S^2);$ it's said that $M$ and $N$ are *stably diffeomorphic*. This theorem is due to [Wall](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/w4.pdf) (it's the result of that paper + the work of Freedman: h-cobordant 4-manifolds are homeomorphic).

This tells us that if we want to find an invariant that can tell apart non-diffeomorphic smooth structures on a 4-manifold, it had better *not* play nicely with connected sum!

Comment: "it had better not play nicely with connected sum" -- sorry, I don't quite understand the wording, isn't there a typo here? I do understand what you mean, but you may want to edit the answer for a clearer wording.

Comment: @Alexander No typo. Call your invariant $D$. Because of the above, if you have some formula relating $D(M\sharp N)$ to $D(M)$ and $D(N)$ - say, $D(M \sharp N) = D(M) +D(N)$ - then $D$ could not distinguish between homeomorphic, but not diffeomorphic, smooth manifolds.

Comment: Thank you! I do understand the meaning, I only meant grammar/style: "you'd better not play with connected sum" or "it does not play nicely with connected sum" or so. OK, I guess it's my non-native English...