# If $A \times B$ is a Lie group, are both $A$ and $B$ Lie groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, lie-groups

Suppose $A,B$ are smooth manifolds and there exists a binary operation on the product manifold $A \times B$ making it into a Lie group.

1. Does this guarantee that there exist binary operations on both $A$ and $B$ making them each into Lie groups?
2. If the answer is yes, can it be done in such a way that the product group $A \times B$ is equal to the original Lie group?
3. If the answer to that is yes, is it necessary?

I tried briefly to find a counterexample browsing a table of Lie groups but was unsuccessful.

Comment: I'm not sure about the first part, but it is definitely possible for $G$ to be diffeomorphic to $A \times B$ with $A$ and $B$ groups but not have $G = A \times B$ as groups.  For example: $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ is diffeomorphic to $SL_n(\mathbb{C}) \times \mathbb{C}^\times$ as a manifold, but it is not isomorphic to $SL_n(\mathbb{C}) \times \mathbb{C}^\times$ as a group.

Comment: According to [this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1178730/1421), $SO(8)$ is diffeomorphic to $SO(7)\times S^7$, but $S^7$ has no Lie group structure. Maybe somebody can find a reference for a proof of that diffeomorphism?

Comment: I took the liberty of numbering the questions. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "is it necessary" in question 3; can you clarify?

Comment: One famous example is given by an exotic $R^4$: It is a smooth $4$-manifold   $W$   which is not diffeomorphic to $R^4$ but homeomorphic to $R^4$. However, it is known that $W\times R$ is diffeomorphic to $R^5$ since there are no exotic $R^5$'s.

Comment: By "equal" The OP meant "diffeomorphic"?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I meant "is it necessary" with regards to the second question, ie an affirmative answer to the question "is the only way to put a group structure on the factors of $A \times B$ making each $A,B$ into Lie groups the way that will make their product group equal to the original Lie group?". At this point the question is moot, given professor Lee's counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question 2 has well-known counterexamples. Generally, it's known that every connected Lie group $G$ is diffeomorphic to a product $K \times \mathbb{R}^n$ where $K$ is its [maximal compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_compact_subgroup) subgroup, but $G$ is generally not isomorphic to a product of Lie groups diffeomorphic to $K$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$. A nice small example is $G = SL_2(\mathbb{R})$, whose maximal compact is $SO(2)$, and hence which is diffeomorphic to a product

$$SL_2(\mathbb{R}) \cong S^1 \times \mathbb{R}^2.$$

(this can be established quite explicitly, e.g. using [Iwasawa decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iwasawa_decomposition)). However, $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ has a simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{R})$, so it isn't isomorphic to any nontrivial product of positive-dimensional Lie groups.

Answer (score 4):

1. First, the example mentioned by Jack Lee: The group $SO(8)$ acts transitively on the unit sphere $S^7$ with point-stabilizers isomorphic to $SO(7)$. This gives $SO(8)$ structure of a principal $SO(7)$-bundle over $S^7$. This bundle is nothing but the orthonormal frame bundle of $S^7$. Since $S^7$ is parallelizable, its orthonormal frame bundle is trivial, hence, $SO(8)$ is diffeomorphic to $S^7\times SO(7)$. However, $S^7$ (as any sphere apart from $S^1$ and $S^3$) [is not homeomorphic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12453/is-there-an-easy-way-to-show-which-spheres-can-be-lie-groups) to any Lie group.
2. A more difficult example is an exotic $R^4$: It is a smooth 4-dimensional manifold $W$ homeomorphic to $R^4$ but not diffeomorphic to it (there is actually continuum of diffeomorphism classes of exotic $R^4$'s). On the other hand, $W\times R$ is homeomorphic to $R^5$, hence, diffeomorphic to $R^5$ since there are no exotic $R^n$'s for $n\ne 4$. Now, $R^5$, of course, has structure of a Lie group. But if an $n$-dimensional Lie group is contractible, it has to be diffeomorphic to $R^n$. I am quite sure the same works in one dimension lower, when one uses $W$ equal to the Whitehead manifold.